Why does my Bash script give an error at the end of ps command when I terminate background a process?
So for my class I am tasked to write a script, everything works fine until after the ps command finishes output it also adds an error message (script.sh: line 42: PID Terminated   sleep 900 &) after what seems to be successfully output for the ps command on line 42.
script.sh:
#!/bin/bash

# Clears screen and displays current running processes
clear
ps

# Pauses for 10 seconds
sleep 10

# Displays Parent Process ID using $BASHPID env var (expands to subshells)
# $BASHPID requires Bash 4 or later
echo
echo -e "Parent Process ID:\t$BASHPID"
echo

# Creates background process: Pause for 900 seconds
sleep 900 &

# Displays background jobs
jobs -l

# Pauses for 10 seconds
sleep 10

# Uses jobs -l, grep (in case other jobs are running), and cut to find PID of background job and saves it as a variable
bgjob=$(jobs -l | grep "sleep 900" | cut -d" " -f2)

# Terminates the background job created
kill -SIGTERM $bgjob
# Displays current processes so you can verify background job sucsessfully terminated
echo
ps
echo

# Pauses for 10 seconds
sleep 10

exit 0

I was expecting it to have a clean output like output from the ps command and maybe some sort of output for the kill command or at least the error to be on that line

Please don't include line numbers -- a good [mre] is code we can copy, paste, and run ourselves to see the same problem (and thus test our answers) without needing other changes.

That said, there's a lot that's odd about this code. Job control is generally turned off altogether in noninteractive shells. The general Right Thing is to store the PID of your jobs directly, not to try to pull them out of jobs -l.

That is, sleep 900 & sleep_pid=$! -- no job control needed, no grep needed, etc. And if job control is turned off you don't get the message you're asking about.

Beyond that, though -- signals are delivered asynchronously; it's completely normal for kill -TERM to take some time to be enacted, so running ps directly after with no delay could give you unexpected results.

@CharlesDuffy What do you mean by store the PID directly? This is not something we went over in the class. You say not to use jobs -l but my assignment instructions are "The script will use the jobs -l command AND the cut command to obtain the PID
of the background job." It seems every time I post my scripts asking for help I'm told I'm doing it the wrong way and whatever the right way is not something that will get me any points. Starting to think I'll get this degree and not know how to do anything I'm asked to do.

Your assignment is written by someone who doesn't know what they're doing. jobs is specified in the optional interactive annex of POSIX sh -- noninteractive shells aren't required to have a jobs command at all. The proper way for noninteractive shells to read the PID of processes they started is using $!.

In https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/jobs.html, see the UP flag -- that means the command is part of the "user portability" extensions, not the baseline spec for what a shell is guaranteed to provide.

@CharlesDuffy Also what is the half after the & do in this sleep 900 & sleep_pid=$! I don't entirely understand this is not how the professor showed us and nor was job control mentioned, it has to run on the school server and I don't have much privilege on that server

@Aaron The built-in variable $! is the PID of the last background process that was started.  sleep 900 & starts a background process, and sleep_pid=$! saves its PID in the variable.

& is like ; excect it puts the thing in the left-hand side in the background (and stores the PID that thing was assigned in $!), so sleep_pid=$! is just another command, one that copies the PID from $! into a variable named sleep_pid so you can later run kill "$sleep_pid" or such. The reason to put it on the same line is robustness -- so extra commands added to the script in the future can't change $! between when it's set and copied to the variable that'll hold it longer-term; you could put sleep_pid=$! on a separate line and it'd still work, but I don't recommend it.

@Barmar Thank you, that makes sense, the & was not described further than "adding it after a command will run it in the background" I was unaware I could run other commands following it

BTW, echo -e isn't good practice either -- see the excellent writeup Stephane did over on [unix.se] at Why is printf better than echo?; the POSIX echo specification itself recommends using printf instead (in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, see the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections).

@CharlesDuffy Thank you so much for the help! This all makes sense, I will fix up my script as best as I can while still following the directions.

No worries. BTW, none of this is stuff I would consider someone unhireable for if it happened in a job interview. It's a place where you'd get bonus points for getting it right, but not be written off for getting it wrong; the way to fail one of my interviews on shell scripting is more about writing scripts with injection vulnerabilities or other major security issues.

(Also, not just here but in general, think about running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ -- which is also a downloadable/locally-installable tool -- and reading the wiki pages linked for any warnings it identifies).

Going back to the job control part -- how are you starting your script? If you're running it with ./scriptname job control should be off by default unless you explicitly turned it back on with set -m or by starting the script with bash -m. You might have it on if you were running the script in your preexisting interactive shell by using . scriptname or source scriptname instead of ./scriptname -- don't do that.

Why can't I use job control in a bash script? might be useful background for understanding what I was saying earlier.

It is not an error message from your script. The message comes from the fact that you killed a background job. You'll get the message when the next prompt comes.
As an example, try:
$ sleep 50 &
$ kill $! ; sleep 5
[1]+  Terminated              sleep 50
$ sleep 50 &
$ kill $!
$ #give an enter
[1]+  Terminated              sleep 50

